# "come along" vs "along come"

Tags: word-order

Why is ***along came*** used in this way in the following sentence?

> Probably back in some previous biology course, you learned that snakes evolved from lizards and that the first snakes weren't venomous and then **along came** more advanced snakes, the venomous snakes.

What is the differences between *come along* and *along come*? Is it inversion? What is the meaning? How could I use it?

I know several ways of using inversion but I have not seen anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "along came" means something or someone passed by the observer, but it is often used in a figurative sense to talk about something that comes to pass in history.  For example:

> Along came calculus.

Meaning at some point in history, calculus came into existence.

"Come along" is more of an invitation for someone to join you on a trip.  This could also be used in a figurative sense and is often used in documentaries:

> Come along as we explore the history of Greece.